# Facebook game login screen background image

Tags: facebook, image, authentication

Spent some time trying to find info on customizing login background image. The only thing i've found about it is that it's possible :D

here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook/login?locale=en_US#clientsidelogin  and above the header. Still can't get how to do it

Comment: What are you currently trying? Have some code we can inspect? Just the relevant portions, please.

Comment: @Frecklefoot i've got a game on Facebook. What I'm trying is to customize an image, that facebook shows during oauth login dialog (www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth). At this moment, it seems to show one of screenshots, but it's blurred (automatically by facebook), while the game from the doc shows image clearly. I guess the problem is that they show image in their iframe, while the dialog popup is called via JS, and in my case we do redirect to some native Facebook page that redirects user back to app after giving permissions. Not sure what piece of code to show, hope it became more clear

Comment: What that screenshot shows, is simply the content that the app itself is displaying, before it is calling the login dialog. The images you upload in the App Details section are not used here; they only come into play when login is triggered from a place like App Center.

Comment: Thanks to @CBroe. Problem was solved (just forgot to write it :)).